# I'm getting the 'circular dependency' Android Dagger Hilt error

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I checked everything from scratch, but I couldn't find the error. I couldn't find the error, what could it be?

I am getting the following compilation error;

```xml
HomeViewModel.java:6: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class HomeViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
             ^
```

Manifes File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.movielistandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.example.movielistandroid.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MovieListAndroid">
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Application.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.movielistandroid

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application() {}
```

AppModule.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.movielistandroid.di

import com.example.movielistandroid.BuildConfig
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.remote.MovieService
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories.MoviesRepository
import com.example.movielistandroid.usecase.repositories.MoviesRepositoryImpl
import com.example.movielistandroid.utils.Constants
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.components.ApplicationComponent
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): ...
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): ...
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ...


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoviesRepository(movieService: MovieService):  ...

}
```

MoviesRepository.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories

import MoviesResponseModel
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.remote.MovieService

interface MoviesRepository {
    ...
}
```

MoviesRepositoryImpl.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.movielistandroid.usecase.repositories

import com.example.movielistandroid.data.remote.MovieService
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.remote.MovieService.Companion.MOVIE_API_KEY
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories.MoviesRepository
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

class MoviesRepositoryImpl
@Inject constructor(
    private val movieService: MovieService
) : MoviesRepository {

    override suspend fun getCurrentPlayingMovies() = movieService.getCurrentPlayingMovies(apiKey = MOVIE_API_KEY)
    override suspend fun getUpComingMovies() = movieService.getUpComingMovies(apiKey = MOVIE_API_KEY);
}
```

HomeViewModel.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.movielistandroid.ui.home

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.liveData
import com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories.MoviesRepository
import com.example.movielistandroid.utils.Resource
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import javax.inject.Inject

class HomeViewModel
@Inject constructor(
    private val moviesRepository: MoviesRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    fun getUpComingMovies() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
       ...
    }

    fun getCurrentPlayingMovies() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
       ...
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.java (generated)

```java
package com.example.movielistandroid.ui.home;

import java.lang.System;

@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 5, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\"\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u000f\b\u0007\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0004J\u0012\u0010\u0005\u001a\u000e\u0012\n\u0012\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\b0\u00070\u0006J\u0012\u0010\t\u001a\u000e\u0012\n\u0012\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\b0\u00070\u0006R\u000e\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003X\u0082\u0004\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000\u00a8\u0006\n"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/movielistandroid/ui/home/HomeViewModel;", "Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel;", "moviesRepository", "Lcom/example/movielistandroid/data/repositories/MoviesRepository;", "(Lcom/example/movielistandroid/data/repositories/MoviesRepository;)V", "getCurrentPlayingMovies", "Landroidx/lifecycle/LiveData;", "Lcom/example/movielistandroid/utils/Resource;", "LMoviesResponseModel;", "getUpComingMovies", "app_debug"})
public final class HomeViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    private final com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories.MoviesRepository moviesRepository = null;
    
    @javax.inject.Inject()
    public HomeViewModel(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    com.example.movielistandroid.data.repositories.MoviesRepository moviesRepository) {
        super();
    }
    
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<com.example.movielistandroid.utils.Resource<MoviesResponseModel>> getUpComingMovies() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<com.example.movielistandroid.utils.Resource<MoviesResponseModel>> getCurrentPlayingMovies() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.movielistandroid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def glide_version = "4.12.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'



    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'


    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"


    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0'

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"



    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add @HiltViewModel to your ViewModel class https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

Comment: Yes, just add this Annotation @HiltViewModel on top of ViewModel class

Comment: I added '@HiltViewModel' annotation but I have still this error. @IR42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@HiltViewModel` in your vm,if you using hilt vm factory to inject vm in your activity/fragment.

Also, you can just bind your `MoviesRepositoryImpl` with `MoviesRepository`
Instead of writing a provider for it, you are already using constructor injection for `MoviesRepositoryImpl`

How about -

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface MoviesRepositoryImplModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindMoviesRepositoryImpl(movieRepoImp: MoviesRepositoryImpl): MoviesRepository
}
```

and remove

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoviesRepository(movieService: MovieService): MoviesRepository = MoviesRepositoryImpl(movieService)
```

from `AppModule`

Comment: I did what you wrote but the problem persists. Same error. :(

Comment: Can you add, code snippet, how are you injecting VM in activity/fragment? And also can you try running app with option --stracktrace in compiler option for more detailed error logs.

Comment: I found the problem with --stacktrace compiler option. My problem is not about the dagger hilt. I was getting this problem because the model class I was creating didn't have a "package" prefix.

Comment: @SalihCan thanks for your info!! I literally go and check one-by-one about the `package` thing and it resolved!. `Dagger-hilt` should be improved their error prompting skill omg!

Comment: @SalihCan Could you please explain further?

Comment: Thanks @SalihCan for sharing. I faced the same error

Answer (score 0):

My problem was different from OP, but I had the same error message and it was caused because I forgot to use `kapt` for Hilt compile dependencies.

changed from:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42'
```

to:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42'
```